# Segfault when using pybind11 wrappers in C++

Tags: python, c++, segmentation-fault, pybind11

I have an example with the following structure.

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── ext
│   └── pybind11
└── main.cpp
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(notworking)
add_subdirectory(ext/pybind11)
add_executable(notworking
  main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(notworking PRIVATE python3.6m)
target_link_libraries(notworking PRIVATE pybind11)
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

int main() { py::object decimal = py::module::import("decimal"); }
```

---

And now upon running

```
╰─ ./notworking
[1]    14879 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./notworking
```

What am I missing to get this module to load properly here? I have scoured the [documentation](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), in particular the build systems section, but have come up empty.

It also seems to be the case for me when using other wrappers in pybind11 from C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've got a modified version of your example to run with both local and native modules. Basic procedure was as follows:

Install python3.6, python3.6-dev and CMake (3.10 latest). I only have python3.6 installed (version 3.6.3)

Download pybind11-master from [github](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11) and unzip. In the unzipped folder:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make check -j 4
sudo make install
```

Create the "notworking" project with simple main.cpp and calc.py sources:

Main.cpp:

```
#include <pybind11/embed.h> 
namespace py = pybind11;

int main() {
    py::scoped_interpreter guard{};

    py::print("Hello, World!"); 

    py::module decimal = py::module::import("decimal");
    py::module calc = py::module::import("calc");
    py::object result = calc.attr("add")(1, 2);
    int n = result.cast<int>();
    assert(n == 3);
    py::print(n);
}
```

Calc.py (this must be present in the same folder:)

```
def add(i, j):
    return i + j
```

My simple CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(notworking)

find_package(pybind11 REQUIRED) 

add_executable(notworking main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(notworking PRIVATE pybind11::embed)
```

Building and running gives the output:

```
Hello, World!
3
```

Hope this is of some help.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this, I was having this error and when I added `py::scoped_interpreter guard{};` it fixed it.